# django authorization with social network, password managing

Tags: django, authorization

i'm making authorization through social network, using my custom user model (it also contain usual users, they can log in with email and password). I'm thinking about managing password of my 'social users'. I can define some password in setting for all of them and use it to log them in. Or generate random passwords and store them in special model, but it making useless password salt and hash in user model.
Can't leave them blank because it will be possible to login with this email without password.

Comment: Why don't you just use django-social-auth? `https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth`

Comment: it's easier to write something by yourself, then make someone's code act like you want. I had some problems with getting email from some social network.

Comment: I think you should learn how to use other people's code. This is the core of development process nowadays.

Comment: I think you're right. But still wanna be involved in all details of this process to understand what's going on down there, so it will be easier in future to find problem spots.

Comment: @SergiiV. You should user python-social-auth and read the docs carefuly, because if you do not get email by default, then you should enable it in settings. Also, not every social networks provide emails. For example, twitter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth), it has features needed for handling social accounts